# How to solve this circle arc angle problem algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*The radius of circle O is 34 cm. The arc formed by angle $\beta$ is $3.4\pi$ cm long. What is the measure of angle β to the nearest whole?*

The answer is $18^{\circ}$. But I'm not sure how to get there. Circumference$= 2 \pi r = 68\pi$ but what's the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know formula length of arc $l=r\theta$

or 
$$\theta={l \over r}={3.4\pi \over 34}={\pi \over 10} radians=18°$$

Answer (score 0):

The length of the whole circle (an angle of $2\pi$ radians) is $2\pi r$, so by a simple rule of three, you have that the arclength formed by an angle $\beta$(in radians) will be $\beta r$. So, we want to find $\beta$ such that $\beta(34)=3.4\pi$.

From here you get $\beta=\pi/10$. Now, note that $\pi/10$ radians is 18 degrees.